# Makefile: realpath function on windows for gnu toolchain (yagarto)

Tags: gcc, makefile, gnu-make, toolchain

I am trying to write some makefiles on windows for arm gnu toolchain. (yagarto.de)

But for

```
MY_LIBC_PATH = $(realpath D:/temp//_latest//../)
```

I get

```
D:/privat/stm32/eclipse-juno_workspace/yagarto_test/D:/temp
```

My goal is to get only second part(D:/temp), the first part(D:/privat/stm32/eclipse-juno_workspace/yagarto_test/) is my working directory..

I supose realpath is a make function in this case...
Any idea how to get only **D:/temp**?

Answer (score 1):

This is a known problem in GNU make. For example, see [this post](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/make-w32/2008-02/msg00004.html) in the `make-w32` list. That post also proposes a workaround.